# Checking if one element of an array's index is equal to the second element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this little script that will check if one element of an array (`arr[0]`) is equal to the second element of the array (`arr[1]`). However when it checks the following array I would expect it to return `false`, yet it returns `true`. so my questions are, why does this return `true`, and how can I fix it to return `false` like expected?

```
function mutation(arr) {
  var elem0 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var elem1 = arr[1].toLowerCase();

  for(var x=0; x < elem1.length; x++){
    check = elem0.indexOf(elem1[x]);
    if(check === -1){
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]); //returns true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you place the `return true` to soon

you need to place it after the `for` statement like so

```
 function mutation(arr) {
  var elem0 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var elem1 = arr[1].toLowerCase();

  for(var x=0; x < elem1.length; x++){
    check = elem0.indexOf(elem1[x]);
    if(check === -1){
      return false;
    }

  }
  return true;
}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]); //returns false
```

Comment: Why does it matter where it is? Meaning why would when it's inside the `for` loop return true, but outside the loop return `false`?

Comment: when you place it in the `for` loop its return the loop on the first iteration when you place it outside the `for` loop its check **all** of the chars and if none of them return false is return true

Comment: Oh! Okay that makes sense. Hey cool, thank you very much. I'll accept this in five minutes

Answer (score 1):

You're looping over a characters in a string (see what `elem1` actually is), and therefore you get `true` because the first character of `hey`, which is `h`, is indeed found within the string `hello`.

If you want to wait for it to finish iterating over the whole string, use a boolean flag, and then return the value of that flag when the iterations are over.

However, seems you just want to compare the two elements:

```
return elem0 === elem1;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have this little script that will check if one element of an array
>   (arr[0]) is equal to the second element of the array (arr[1])

It returns true since `e` is in both the elements **hello** and **hey**

Your code is essentially iterating over all the characters in the string.

You need to simply check

```
function mutation(arr) {
  return arr[0].toLowerCase() == arr[1].toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression of this question has some logical flaws or at least some lacking points. Such as the given condition means that all the items in the array must be equal. If this is the case then just one tiny piece of instruction is sufficient

```
myArray.every(e => e == myArray[0])
```

```js
var a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    b = ["hello", "hey"];

document.write("<pre> a array :" + a.every(e => e == a[0]) + "</pre>");
document.write("<pre> b array :" + b.every(e => e == b[0]) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: I like that, it's straight forward, however, I was trying to see if the array was inside of the other array